# Get Gulp pipes of dependencies

Tags: gulp, gulp-newer

I have a gulpfile with some tasks. All task are combined in a default task, that has dependencies to all others tasks. I want to add a deploy task. The deploy can take a list of files. I want only deploy changed files.

Is there a way to get the pipes of all dependencies? Or any other way, without merge everything into one task?

Here a simple sample to explain:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css']);

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(newer('./dist/app.js'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/**/*.css')
        .pipe(newer('./dist/style.css'))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('deploy', ['default'], function () {
    gulp.src('./dist/*')
    // Here I want only files changed in dist
        .pipe(debug());
});
```

Update:

Here some more of my task:

```
gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css', 'images', 'templates']);

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/images/*')
        .pipe(newer('./dist/app/images'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/app/images'));

gulp.task('templates', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(newer('./dist/app/templates.js'))
        .pipe(minifyHTML({ empty: true }))
        .pipe(templateCache({ module: 'app' }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/app'));
```

Comment: you would need to change all tasks to work on only changed files

Comment: The two task css and js work with newer only on changed files. But how I get the other tasks work only the changed files?

Comment: cant see other tasks in ur code

Answer (score 1):

I added a deployed folder, where i keep track of all files that a deployed.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css']);

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(newer('./dist/app.js'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/**/*.css')
        .pipe(newer('./dist/style.css'))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('deploy', ['default'], function () {
    gulp.src('./dist/*')
        .pipe(newer('./deployed'))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./deployed'))
});
```